# Passing a value between chained Promises in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing a Stripe payment module in a Firebase web application.

I create a Stripe charge through a Cloud Function, as follow:

```
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('...').onWrite(event => {
....
    let chargeStatus;

return stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key})
    .then(returnedcharge => {
        chargeStatus = returnedcharge.status;
        return event.data.adminRef.set(returnedcharge)
    })
    .then(() => {
        return admin.database().ref(`/stripeCardCharges/${event.params.orderId}`).set({'status': chargeStatus});
    })
    .catch(error => {
        ...
    })
```

As you see I try to follow the advices from the Firebase team to carefully chain the promises.

However I need the `returnedcharge` object to be used in two promises, chained one after the other:

1. The first time to write the entire object to the Real Time Database
2. The second time because I want to write `returnedcharge.status` to the database, but at another node (because of different access rights)

I have then created a variable that I populate in the first promise and use later in the next one.

My question is: Is this the good approach?

Another linked question (for which I think the answer is "no"!): would it be possible (and make sense!) to combine the two database write (i.e. set) in one promise only? If yes, what do you return then?

Comment: thanks! I got my head scratching how to get the parameters in promises, it's just local variables in a function - and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks OK to me.  Seems to get the job done without problems.